# How to add layout style options for TYPO3 Content Element table?

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

In TYPO3 there's a content element called 'table' (not the one in the RTE). Creating this content element you can choose a background color. How can I add my own background color and/or change the current ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

#### In your Page TSconfig add

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.table_bgColor {
    addItems.105 = NEW TABLE STYLE
}
```

The ID `105` can be whatever ID you like - even a string. Just make sure you do not use a value already in use. You can inspect the select box in the TYPO3 backend with your developer tool. The label `NEW TABLE STYLE` can be what ever you like. Its the label you will see in the backend.

#### In your TypoScrip template setup

```
tt_content.table.20.color.105 = #fff
```

Remember to replace `105` with your own ID from your page TSconfig. The value `#fff` is just a dummy value. You could use it dynamically in `_CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE` but I usually just style it directly in my stylesheet.

At this point you should be able to create a table element and select the background color `NEW TABLE STYLE` and in the frontend when you inspect your table your should see a class named `contenttable-color-105` which you can style as you like.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I searched for.
With `removeItems = 1, 2, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244` I remove some of the standard options, so only the needed one is available.

Comment: I´m Glad I could help :)